# How to optimize MIN + ORDER + LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I try to implement backward pagination in my app. Data comes from a large NoSQL database and if I do pagination in the trivial way, then I see that the further page I jump to, the more time it takes me to get there. To improve performanace I plan to use MySQL table which stores just indices. What I want from MySQL - to find a starting index of the page as fast as possible. This approach on a table with 3 million rows takes almost 3 second to get and index:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM index_77635_ ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $large_skip_number
```

As you see, I try to find a row with the least index so to jump to those rows which were added earlier. Probably, there is a better way to implement this task.

**EDIT**

The correct query which works quite good (=relatively fast, or at least faster than in pure Mongo) turned out to be this one:

```
SELECT a.id FROM index_77635_ a 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM (
        SELECT id FROM index_77635_ ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $skip,$limit
    ) t 
) b ON a.id = b.id
```

In this case I try to find the starting (that is maximum for backward pagination) index, and then in mongo I query chucnk of data up to this index.

Comment: Your query only returns one row.  The `order by` and `limit` are superfluous.

Comment: Assuming you also have an index (most likely primary key) on the id?

Comment: Yes, there is an index

Comment: You're asking us to optimize the (rather elaborate) solution you implemented to optimize the performance of your application. Maybe it might be better to find a different way of optimizing the application.

Comment: I've already done it. MondgoDb + MySQL (storing just indices) beats pure MongoDb. On a table with 3 millions of rows navigation to some far pages takes 10 seconds in pure Mongo, whereas in MondgoDb + MySQL it takes around 6 seconds